# How to add PlatformToolset to a VC++ project with VS2017 to solve error LNK2038?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Just run into a link error with VS2017 when building a VC++ project:

> LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1900' in xxx.obj

This is caused by the mismatched **Platform Toolset** in the project property:
[image: Platform Toolset]

It is `Visual Studio 2017 (v141)` by default, but the 3rd-party static libraries were built with VS2012, whose platform toolset is `v110`.

Is it possible to add VS2012 platform toolset to a VS2017 VC++ project **without** installing VS2012?

Comment: Why downvote without any comment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. I failed to find a solution without installing VS2012. But there is no need to buy a license of VS2012: just use VS2012 express.

After installing VS2012 Express for Desktop:

[image: Platform Toolset]